Google Chrome shows "Other tabs share a process with this tab, which may result in an unexpected DevTools experience" when opening the dev tools
The title says it all, Google Chrome warns "Other tabs share a process with this tab, which may result in an unexpected DevTools experience" when opening the dev tools.
I searched online for this text, however, I was only able to find source code matches.
Does anyone have any idea on how this can be mitigated, so that I can get my Chrome to start behaving predictably again?
Device: MacBook Pro 13-inch, M1, 2020
OS: Mac OS Ventura 13.6.3 (22G436)

It's https://crbug.com/324096747 and it's already disabled via google servers. Try restarting or updating Chrome.

Thank you, reinstall fixed it. Sadly missed the chance to try restarting or updating it.
